# Relax NG in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, relaxng

Is there any free software plugin which adds RelaxNG support to Eclipse? I mean syntax highlighting, showing hints after Ctrl+Space pressed, etc.

I have found only some articles about this topic and they are several years old [as of 2013]. They say that RelaxNG support is developing in Webtools, but now there is no mention of RelaxNG.

So does anybody know something more about this, or know some other free software project (actually working) which add RelaxNG support into Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

The oXygen XML Editor (commercial software) has such support - it is available as an Eclipse plugin.

See: http://www.oxygenxml.com/

Comment: Hm, I forget one thing – free solution. But thanks for tip anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you install [wildwebdeveloper](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) which provides now relaxng support. Validation completion in xml files based on relaxng xml schema/ relaxng compact syntax schema should work and it is free.

You can see [those relaxng features with vscode](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-xml/blob/main/docs/Features/RelaxNGFeatures.md#relaxng-features) since wildwebdeveloper uses the same xml language server than vsode-xml